# Google Fonts look like crap in Google Chrome

Tags: wordpress, fonts, cross-browser, typography

bit.ly/ZwCln9

I have like 3-4 Google Web Fonts going on here and it looks mint in IE/FF, but the fonts are choppy and gross in Chrome. I read you can download svg files or something onto the server? I'm using Wordpress and need step-by-step help with this because I suck.

Where do I get the files and where do I upload them to via ftp? Whats the code I use in CSS?

Thanks for all of your help :)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google webfonts render choppy in Chrome on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953037/google-webfonts-render-choppy-in-chrome-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use SVG if you don't want to. The fonts will never look the same across all browsers because each uses a different engine. However, you can always reset to make it look as close as possible. Here is a quick reset that you can add at the top of your css file that will solve this issue.

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal
}
```

Or you could just get a full CSS Reset, like the YUI reset, or Normalize.