# Chrome SVG webfonts weird characters in select input

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rendering, webfonts

Chrome 26.0.1410.64m on Windows 8 has problems rendering WebFonts. It is a known problem and a solution is to first serve the svg version of the font instead of the woff version. It fixes the anti-aliasing and makes font look pretty again.

The downside of this method is the weird rendering inside the  element inside select inputs.

I added a jsfiddle to see it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/4mSpv/6/.

The CSS is as simple as it can be.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('https://raw.github.com/louh/website/master/fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg#montserratregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
select {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

I remove the local installation of a font and noticed an other windows 7 computer doing the same. Anyone knows what is going on with chrome? (IE, Firefox, Safari all render fine)

[image: Select input rendering font chrome]

PS: Other browser fonts not included in JSFiddle to filter out the problem and each browser have their own quirks (not allowing font-size etc) but render the text fine

Comment: Could you please share the link to the bug report here?

Comment: I just created one as I tested on more devices with chrome and can verify the issue. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232099&thanks=232099&ts=1366149037

Comment: Btw, it's not just Win8, same problem on OSX Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to solve this problem.

> This is NOT a Regression issue and is existing from M24.

I submitted a bug report and it [Weird character rendering in option menu](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232099&thanks=232099&ts=1366149037)

Comment: Given the priority they are giving the font rendering problems in general it's unlikely that we'll see this fixed soon. For what it's worth I starred the bug report to give it just a bit more weight. Until then, I'll fall back to generic font for my select boxes

Comment: yea I switched back to normal font as well in select boxes. It is kinda annoying and easy to reproduce. I agree they have loads of font rendering bugs already and this is probably an edge case for them

Answer (score 2):

As automaticoo stated, it is a known issue with Chrome. However, you can workaround the issue with a technique mentioned in the selected answer for this post: [Google Webfonts Render Choppy in Chrome on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953037/google-webfonts-render-choppy-in-chrome-on-windows).

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  select {
    font-family: Arial; /* standard font */
  }
}
```

That way you can use whatever font you want for browsers that still work, and replace it with a generic HTML font for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was actually looking for an answer for this, and I stumbled upon this question. I noticed this bug still exists today ( I just met it, such a happy meeting... ). Now I only found 1 solution, which is placing the svg font last in the @font-face declaration (this also means including all other formats). The only problem is that, when you for exampling try fixing the font rendering (to make it all smooth and stuff) you'd actually put the svg first. 
Here are some examples to demonstrate it

1: SVG font last, no crisp font, options are displayed right

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSansLight';
src: url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
src: url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#open_sanslight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

[image: Example 1]

So as you can see, the options in the select box show just fine, but the font really isn't that crips, just look at "Register" (you might notice this better in comparison with my second example)

2: SVG font last, crisp font, stupid options in select

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSansLight';
src: url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
src: url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#open_sanslight') format('svg'),
     url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

[image: Example 2]

Now you will see that the font is a lot more crisp but the select is really stupid.

I suggest adding another font-face with the svg last just for select's. This will keep your fonts crisp throughout the website but display the options just fine.