# Chrome inconsistent Rendering elements with offset

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I worked on a website and used media queries heavenly to make the site responsive.

But I experience very weird errors in Chrome where it is rendering elements in the wrong positions (looks like it is doing aligning multiple elements across the page to the right.

I will attach a screenshot of  wrong alignment. As you can see the text in the top-bar goes beyond the lines. In the middle every element that is normally centered is offset to the right. Also in the bottom bar it is throwing text elements that are normally spaced next to eachother on top of eachother.

To see the the website online https://tunepitch.com/. The weird thing is that chrome sometimes renders it wrong but a lot of time it shows correct. It can go away by dragging the window but a more effective approach is to kill the browser and restart it.

**Does anyone know why chrome is having this issue and what is causing it in my css?**

What I tried :

- Check Audit in chrome developer tools
- Modify style variables in the inspector
- disable cache
- disable javascript

**UPDATE**

I spend some time debugging the css. Added css line by line and still can't find the root issue. What I noticed with all elements that are misaligned is that the width is not correctly calculate by webkit browsers. I hope the extra image can point it out. (esp when you hover the text should turn purple on hover. As you can see it is only purple to a certain amount of width.

**UPDATE 2**
To be clear with javascript turned off the problem still occurs. I tried to make a simple testcase for this problem but because the problem is so inconsistent I can't nail it down to a simple css block.

I am using chrome 31.0.1650.57 on Windows 8.1. One of my clients uses Windows 7 in combination with 31.0.1650.57 as well.

**UPDATE 3**
I got a video live that can show the weirdness of the problem. You can see the first time I open chrome it is correct, than I close and open it again and everything is misaligned. When I then inspect the element everything jumps to the right position (it doesn't do this always [youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aqg8ICVtZd4&feature=youtu.be)

**UPDATE 4**
@SetSailMedia is right is was the use of a svg font in Chrome. What is weird is that I used this font in some other websites and never seen this problem. I changed back to load the font from google's webfonts instead of my own hosted font. Which causes the font to become ugly again but it is a better solution than misalignment of elements.

[image: miscalculation webkit]

[image: wrong alignment]

Comment: is js involved in the menu or is it just a css issue? I could not reproduce any issues on my mac book pro chrome.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — **in the question itself**. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: So It looks fine on my macbook pro chrome version 31.0.16 what browsers & operating systems have you tested it in? and versions of chrome?

Comment: Also can't repeat problem `Linux 32.0.1700.6`

Comment: I have the problem on Windows 7 and 8. I had multiple people reproduce it on windows 7 and 8. There is no js involved in the menu, only some media queries when the screen goes to small. The problem is that it is very inconsistent. Sometimes it happens for me the whole day and sometimes it doesn't show up for a few hours.

Comment: I tried to make the problem smaller by slowly removing css code from my webpage. But because the problem is so inconsistent there is no way to reproduce it consistently and I couldn't nail it down to a single css block. :(

Comment: I think it may be related to your use of unsafe web fonts and the way the browser loads the font sources. If you remove any non-standard font, does the problem persist?

Comment: @SetSailMedia I think you are right I disabled the font in a local version and couldn't replicate the problem!. What do you mean by unsafe webfont. As Montserrat the font I use is downloaded from Google Webfonts. (I don't use their script because it doesn't serve the svg for chrome and causes weird aliasing).

Comment: What's I think is happening is the browser is positioning the element based on the standard system font -- before the fancy font loads. As soon as the fancy font downloads and can be rendered, even if it's just milliseconds behind, the alignment ends up slightly off. You might try using JavaScript to clean up, or loading the font files at the very top before any other CSS (not sure whether this will solve things, just a guess). When you sometimes don't see the problem, I think it's because the browser has already cached the font file.

Comment: @SetSailMedia Yeah I would only ever load font files in the header if you aren't doing that already. Otherwise you could potentially have a weird "font-switching" effect which might be causing the issue here.

Comment: the video showing the issue is private!

Comment: Chrome has a lot of issues with svg fonts. There's currently work being done to deprecate its usage. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/_19XaMfHdww/6y2i04n5784J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that svg fonts have a problem in chrome. As pointed out by commenter @Wesabi [in this google group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/_19XaMfHdww/6y2i04n5784J). I tested your link and changed font to a non-svg font and it seems working.

What caused your inconsistency within sessions is that sometimes the font is loaded before the calculation of elements and sometimes after depending in which order the requests comple@te.

The best solution would be to use Google Webfonts even when it makes the font look anti-aliased in chrome, it will default to another font-type.

Chrome also has problems rendering SVG fonts in select boxes for example. To see original question and bug report.

[Original svg problem with select boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045267/chrome-svg-webfonts-weird-characters-in-select-input)

[Google bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232099&thanks=232099&ts=1366149037)

Answer (score -2):

You can try using CSS Reset by Eric Meyer which will remove all the inconsistency among different browser rendering. Here's the code below:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not an inconstancy between browsers. It is an inconstancy in the same browser.