# Chrome select box option text is distorted when open

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-select, text-rendering

The text between the option tags in a select box is not rendering correctly when open in my Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120.

See attached screenshot for a clear illustration of the issue.

When I select an option and focus away from the box the correct option is selected and renders correctly when the select box is closed.

I've tested the same in Canary 39.0.2161.0 and FF and it renders correctly without being distorted.

I've not seen anything like is before.

Anything to do with Chrome's recent font rendering update?

Any help is much appreciated.!

Link to page, form is at the bottom: http://dev.emarkadvantage.com/strategy.php

UPDATE: A fix that worked for me was to move the position of the SVG font down the @font-face stack to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: You should add style on option tag.Can you show your code.

Comment: Here is the link: http://dev.emarkadvantage.com/strategy.php Form is at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this before. Use a standard (i.e. non web) font for your selects. I don't know why web fonts cause a problem...but they do.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045267/chrome-svg-webfonts-weird-characters-in-select-input).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This led me to find the confirmed bug ticket: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290414 I find it strange that it works in Canary but not in Chrome. Maybe that's a sign it will be fixed soon?

Comment: A fix that worked for me was to move the position of the SVG font down the @font-face stack to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You should add class on select tag,

> class="form-control"

```
<select id="category" class="form-control">
     <option value="">Your top callenge today?</option>
     <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
     <option value="Competition">Competition</option>
     <option value="Marketing ROI">Marketing ROI</option>
     <option value="Positioning">Positioning</option>
</select>
```