# Google Webfonts not rendering correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm using the [Roboto](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) font in my website and it's rendering like the following in Chrome (Windows)

[image]

The font renders OK in iOS.

How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Windows ont rendering is tricky, start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953037/google-webfonts-render-choppy-in-chrome-on-windows

Comment: Perfect! Thanks and sorry for the "duplicated" question. I didn't found it before.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Instead using the standard code provided by google,

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I added a `crossorigin="anonymous"` property tag.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Sincerely, I don't know the real reason, but it worked. Hope that works for you too.