# Font looks screwy in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, font-face

I found this answer here regarding graphic design:
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/265/font-face-loaded-on-windows-look-really-bad-which-fonts-are-you-using-that-rend
This is exactly what my fonts are doing, but I'm trying to find out if there's a way to prevent this using html or css or anything web-based.

I'm using "platin" as my font. Do I just need to find a different font?

Any other thoughts on the topic?

Comment: your fonts are doing what? getting aliased? then, no, there's no way in css or html to force anti-aliasing on text.

Comment: Since "Platin" isn't a common font, are you using webfonts to supply them to the browser? Chrome on Windows has a bug report about this (here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692). There are a few workarounds for this, though. If you're using webfonts I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is caused by using web fonts, I found this SO post (and the accepted answer) helpful: [Google webfonts render choppy in Chrome on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953037/google-webfonts-render-choppy-in-chrome-on-windows)

My solution was to use the Webfont Generator tool (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to convert my font into the variety of web formats and copy their provided CSS into my stylesheet. I was using the Fauna One font from Google, so I had to download it from Google and then upload it into FontSquirrel.

The key is to put the SVG line above TTF, so that Chrome uses it first. Here's what worked for me:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Fauna One';
    src: url('fonts/faunaone-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/faunaone-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/faunaone-regular-webfont.svg#fauna_oneregular') format('svg'),
     url('fonts/faunaone-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/faunaone-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

(This is 99% the same as the CSS file generated by the Webfont Generator, just rearranged a bit).

Answer (score 0):

To get webfonts to render with good antialias in Chrome on Windows, you need to use this format in the font declaration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Futura';
    src: url('futura.eot');
    src: url('futura.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('futura.woff') format('woff'),
         url('futura.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('futura.svg#futura') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Futura';
        src: url('futura.svg#futura') format('svg');
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to force Chrome to use the SVG font format. You can do this by moving the url for the .svg version to the top, however Chrome on Windows has had problems with messing up the layout when doing this (up to and including version 30). By overriding the font declaration using a media query, these issues are solved.

Another thing: This trick will cause the browser to download two versions of the font but that's a small price to pay for good looking text!

Also: Sometimes the baseline position doesn't match between OpenType fonts and SVG fonts but you can adjust this by simply editing the SVG font files. SVG fonts are xml based and if you look at the declaration

```
<font-face units-per-em="2048" ascent="1900" descent="-510" />
```

You can change the value for ascent and get it to match the other font format versions.

Comment: Please done't post the exact same answer to multiple questions: it's either not a good fit for all or the questions are duplicates which should be flagged/closed as such.